# JXScrollUp compile

Tags: java, swingx, jgoodies

I didn't find a package contains a class JXScrollUp because of sample source code JXScrollupTest.java. I'm using this classpath:

```
appframework-1.03.jar:swingx-all-1.6.3.jar:SwingSet3.jar:timingframework-1.0.jar:jgoodies-looks-2.5.0.jar:jgoodies-forms-1.5.0.jar:.).
```

How can I compile it?
Many thanks

Lukas

Answer (score 2):

finally found what you mean: the class was renamed to JXTaskPane. That was about a lustrum ago, so wonder where you got that old'ish test class